# TinyMCE editor takes cursor focus while selecting text next to it

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-6

I was able to re-create the functionality on the Demo page: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/

Start selecting the text below the editor
[Selecting Text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ncsky.png)

make sure your mouse is still down while hovering over the tinymce editor
[Still holding cursor down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7g80H.png)

and then release - and you cursor is now in the tinymce editor while the text is still selected.
[Released cursor over TinyMCE, arrow to cursor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qELuT.png)

This has caused issues where the users have gone back to re-select the content in another input element, but that text is already selected - so they drag/drop the text in tinymce (which they don't want to do).

Select of the other element stays, cursor does not enter TinyMCE.